How can I clear the RSS memory used after polars.read_csv()?
Reading a large CSV file at once is too heavy, so I am trying to process it by reading in parts. I physically split the file into 10 pieces, but whether I read one piece or read one piece 10 times, the memory usage theoretically shouldn’t increase, but it seems to keep growing.
When I create the DataFrame object directly without using read_csv, the memory doesn’t increase, which makes me think there’s a leak when reading the file.
It doesn’t seem to be resolved by using gc.collect() or the del keyword, so I’m wondering if there’s a better way to handle this.
polars==1.11.0
import polars as pl

import multiprocessing as mp
import psutil
import os
import gc
import glob
import sys


def read_one():
    mypid = os.getpid()
    proc = psutil.Process(mypid)

    columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']

    filepath = 'test1.csv'

    current_rss = proc.memory_info().rss

    df = pl.read_csv(filepath, has_header=False, new_columns=columns, schema_overrides={c: pl.String for c in columns})

    current_rss2 = proc.memory_info().rss

    print('rss size:', current_rss2-current_rss)


def read_all():
    mypid = os.getpid()
    proc = psutil.Process(mypid)

    columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']

    filepath = 'test*.csv'

    current_rss = proc.memory_info().rss

    df = pl.read_csv(filepath, has_header=False, new_columns=columns, schema_overrides={c: pl.String for c in columns})

    current_rss2 = proc.memory_info().rss

    print('rss size:', current_rss2-current_rss)

def read_loop():
    mypid = os.getpid()
    proc = psutil.Process(mypid)

    columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']

    filelist = glob.glob('test*.csv')

    current_rss = proc.memory_info().rss

    for filepath in filelist:
        df = pl.read_csv(filepath, has_header=False, new_columns=columns,
                         schema_overrides={c: pl.String for c in columns})

        del df
        gc.collect()

    current_rss2 = proc.memory_info().rss

    print('rss size:', current_rss2 - current_rss)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')

    proc = mp.Process(target=read_one, daemon=True)
    proc.start()
    proc.join()

    proc = mp.Process(target=read_all, daemon=True)
    proc.start()
    proc.join()

    proc = mp.Process(target=read_loop, daemon=True)
    proc.start()
    proc.join()

>>>
rss size: 213282816
rss size: 2039447552
rss size: 423301120


Have you tried the Lazy API? e.g. scan_csv instead of read_csv? (Also, setting infer_schema=False will read everything as pl.String if that's what the schema_overrides is doing.)

@jqurious I didn’t know about 'infer_schema'. Thank you for that. Unfortunately, after trying scan_csv, it didn’t reduce memory usage. Specifically, the method of scanning the entire file and then collecting a set number of rows causes both processing time and memory usage to increase as it progresses.

Ah okay. It seems they also have a low_memory=True kwarg: "Reduce memory pressure at the expense of performance." Not sure if that helps here, it's not something I've used.
